# C file cannot see variable defined in #include'd header file

Tags: c, global-variables, header-files

In `a.h` I have

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H 1

const int global_val = 10;

#endif
```

And in `a.c` I have

```
#include "a.h"

int someFunc() {
    return global_val;
}
```

But the compiler (gcc) throws an `error: 'global_int' undeclared` when compiling `a.c`. How can it possibly be undeclared when I've included the header file?

Comment: Is that because you declare `global_val` and reference `global_int`?

Comment: Get some sleep my friend.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when typing out the simplified code. I just checked my actual code and there are no typos like this. I've edited the original post.

Comment: Never ever **define** variables in header files! Headers onyl should have variable _declarations_ only, not definitions.

Comment: Note that only one source file in your program can successfully include your header given that every time it is included, it defines the global variable.  If more than one file includes the header, then there will be multiple definitions when you try to link them together. The rules of the game are different in C++ — but you have this marked as C and not C++.  If you feel you must do it in the header, make it `static const int global_val = 10;` but expect to get 'unused variable' warnings from the compiler if you include the header but don't reference the variable.  So, don't do it!

Answer (score 1):

You should have two files.

A.h

```
  #ifndef A_H
  #define A_H 1

  extern const int global_val;

  #endif
```

and

A.c

```
  #include "A.h"


  const int global_val = 10;
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem. I deleted all my `.o`, `.gch`, and executable files and the code started compiling again. My guess is that the precompiled headers (which I don't even remember making) were tricking the compiler.

Instead of closing the question, I decided to leave this answer it case it helps someone.

Comment: As your approach is 100% wrong, we should keep this answer to show readers how it should not be done.  You had comment already- do not  put any code or data into the header files!!